# Safari is using very high % of CPU for no apparent reason

Tags: safari

I've been having this problem lately where Safari starts hogging the CPU for no apparent reason. It's not a plugin or a specific webpage that's causing the issue, it's actually the Safari process itself:

[image]

What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You don't specify what model of Mac you are using. 130% of a dual-core CPU would be a sizable amount. 130% of an octo-core system is nothing. What Mac are you using, what CPU, how much RAM, etc.

Comment: Macbook Air late 2011, dual-core, 4 GB RAM